# Does Google's Handwriting API work in web browsers yet?

Tags: chromium, handwriting-recognition

I am looking for a handwriting recognition API that I can embed in my web application.

I found this: [Handwriting Recognition API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/handwriting-recognition/) from Google.
The post also refers to a [Demo](https://handwriting-recognition.glitch.me/).

It is my understanding that this API works in all (newer) Chromium based web browsers, i. e. Google Chrome or MS Edge.

I opened the demo in both browsers (Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119 and MS Edge 106.0.1370.42) on my Win-11-64-bit machine. Same error message in both browsers:

> Handwriting recognition API is not supported on this platform.

Any idea why I get this error message? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, recognition API is only available on devices that have ChromeOS.

[Tweet from Chrome Developers](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/1625815388901543936)

Comment: Thank you, M3rt! That explains the problems I had on all machines that I used for testing. None of them works with ChromeOS ;)